# whenever I kill object taking port 3306, it replaces it with a new one

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to open up port 3306 for mysql for XAMPP. Currently there is another mysql running on port 3306. It seems that I have two separate mysql running on my system? I have killed mysql to open the port, and then started mysql through the XAMPP manager and it started up just fine.

Another issue I am having is that I am locked out of phpmyadmin and cannot get back in, but I cant do anything about that until I get XAMPP mysql back up and running.

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 3306
```

Shows:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      30109/mysqld
```

I can run

```
sudo kill -9 30109
```

It seems like it just kills THAT one process. If I run netstat again, it will just replace that process with a new one.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30310/mysqld
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this? Any suggestions on how I can free this up?

Comment: Killing another instance of mysql is not going to solve your problem in long run. Instead, you should make sure that you only have 1 mysqld instance installed and running. You perhaps need to use `apt-get` to install or remove necessary packages.

Comment: any suggestions on how to check which is which? I would like to remove the one I am not using. That way I can fix the other issue I have with phpmyadmin

Comment: Use `dpkg -l | grep mysql` to see installed packages. Use `sudo apt-get remove <unnecessary_package>` to remove, and `sudo apt-get install <wanted_package>` to install. You may also need to use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <wanted_package>` to set up how it autostarts.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone sees this post, and has not found an answer to their own question that is similar to mine (and simply because this has not been answered yet) I will post my own solution.

I ran

```
lsof -i TCP:3306
```

and got the PID, then ran

```
kill 'PID#'
```

and it worked... I dont know exactly why this process worked when the previous didn't, even when the PID# was the same, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then kill the service, I suggest you stop it:

```
sudo service mysqld stop
```

Killing an actively running mysql instance may cause data corruption in your database.